# /Applications/Preview.app no longer exists but is visible in Finder?

Tags: macos

I think this happened after Catalina.

```
sudo ls /Applications/Preview*
```

claims there is no such file, even though the file is perfectly visible in the Finder.

I have a script that relies on it:

```
function manp(){
  man -t $1 | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
}
```

which I can fix by abbreviating to `open -f -a Preview` but still ... where did Preview.app go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to explore over on the following path:

```
/System/Applications/Preview*
```

Comment: Answers should be more than 1 line with no explanation.  You risk getting downvotes with the answer you provided.  Something like this might be better suited to a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: So yes, Apple apps have moved there. googling it doesn't immediately bring up any info but I guess they just did.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll: I would appreciate it if you can mark my answer as accepted one.